# How to inform nodes in MANET during route discovery process regarding the receivng of route reply packet by the source

Tags: ad-hoc-wireless

A node which uses an on-demand routing protocol in a mobile ad hoc network when requires to send a packet to another node which is not in the radio coverage range, would do it by initiating a route request flooding process. Route Request flooding is the process of broadcasting a route request packet to all the neighbor nodes. The neighbor nodes in turn rebroadcast to their neighbors unless they have a fresh route to the destination node or they have already seen the packet before.

My doubt is when any node which possesses a valid route to the destination replies with a route reply packet to the source, how would the other nodes get informed that the source has got the route and the broadcast of route request packet can be stopped.

Comment: What routing protocol are you using ? AODV ? HWMP? There are many old on-demand routing protocols out there.

Comment: I am using DSR routing protocol

Comment: DSR ? In 2014 ?!?

Comment: I have chosen my area of study for my PG as "Flooding attack prevention in MANET". I am just in first semester M.Tech. The base paper I have chosen for implementation is actually implemented in DSR. Do you have any better suggestion??

Comment: Well, It's just that studying how to prevent flooding attacks in DSR is like studying how to stop wasting IP addresses in a classful Internet. Those old forgotten problems have solutions that have been deployed since 15-20 years, most of which involving ditching the whole system instead of trying to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [The Dynamic Source Routing Protocol for Mobile Ad Hoc Networks](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-manet-dsr-00#section-4.1):

> As a node overhears routes being used by others, either by
> promiscuously snooping on them or when forwarding packets, the node
> MAY insert those routes into its Route Cache, leveraging the Route
> Discovery operations of the other nodes.

Comment: Who still uses the prehistoric DSR protocol ?!?